# laravel ajax not posting to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i'm trying to add a post without the page refreshing the using the simplest way by using jquery ajax.

Its not posting to my mysql database, and i don't know why.

i was following along this [tutorial](http://justlaravel.com/ajax-crud-operations-laravel/)

[Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) Looks like something i can use in the future but i just cant wrap my head around it

Any Suggestions ?

**Dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('title')
Dashboard
@endsection

@section('content')

<div class="dashboard eli-main">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-12">
                <h1>{{$user->username}}</h1>

                <h4>What do you have to say?</h4>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" rows="5" placeholder="Your Post"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="add" class="mybtn2">Create Post</button>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
                </form>


                @foreach($posts as $post)


                <article class="post">
                    <h4>{{ $post->user->username }}</h4>
                    <p class="post-bod">
                        {{ $post->body }}
                    </p>
                    <div class="info">
                        made on {{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}
                    </div>
                </article>

                @endforeach

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
$("#add").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/addItem',
        data: {
            '_token': $('textarea[name=_token]').val(),
            'name': $('textarea[name=body]').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if ((data.errors)) {
                $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.error').text(data.errors.name);
            } else {
                $('.error').remove();
                $('#table').append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
            }
        },
    });
    $('#body').val('');

});
```

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Validator;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class PostController extends Controller
{


      public function getDashboard()
       {
           $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
           $cookie = cookie('saw-dashboard', true, 15);
           $users = User::all();
           $user = new User();
   //        return view('dashboard', array('user'=> Auth::user()), compact('users'))->withCookie($cookie);

           return view('dashboard',array('user'=> Auth::user(), 'posts' => $posts,  compact('users')))->withCookie($cookie);
       }

    // public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    // {
    //  $this->validate($request,[
    //      'body' => 'required|max:1000'
    //  ]);

    //  $post = new Post();
    //  $post->body = $request['body'];
    //  $message = 'There was an error';

    //  if($request->user()->posts()->save($post)){
    //      $message = 'Post Successfully Created';
    //  }

    //     return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    // }

       public function postCreatePost(Request $request) {
           $rules = array (
                   'body' => 'required|max:1000'
           );
           $validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules );
           if ($validator->fails ())
               return Response::json ( array (

                       'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag ()->toArray ()
               ) );
               else {
                   $post = new Post();
                   $post->body = $request->body;
                   $post->save();
                   return response ()->json( $post );
               }
       }

}
```

And the route is

```
Route::post ( '/addItem', 'PostController@postCreatePost' );
```

Comment: what is the error in the console? did you check that?

Comment: @imrealashu jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/addItem 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @OwlMan Your if clause in `postCreatePost` doesn't have `{`

Comment: @linktoahref still didn't work, a gave me a parse error when i added the parantesis

Comment: In the **network** tab in the ajax response, are you able to find the error?

Comment: @linktoahref yes, it was  jquery.min.js:4 POST localhost:8000/addItem 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: when you'll click on the ajax response on the right side you'll get the response in detail as html. are you able to spot the *specific* error

Comment: @linktoahref i do, but it point to the jquery main file, and i know the error couldn't be in that.

Comment: @OwlMan If it's 500 then just check the response tab while viewing the particular request in the network tab. and let us know the response.

Comment: (anonymous) @ app.js:6, does that look right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the `body` in the request, when it's actually the `name` that you are sending

Change your controller code as below

```
public function postCreatePost(Request $request) {
    $rules = array(
         'name' => 'required|max:1000'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
       return Response::json (array(
               'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
       ));
    } else {
       $post = new Post();
       $post->body = $request->body;
       $post->save();
       return response()->json( $post );
    }
}
```

You need to add an `preventDefault` functionality to your click or change the button type of add

So in your app.js, make the changes as

```
$("#add").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    //rest of the code

});
```

or

change this

```
<button type="submit" id="add" class="mybtn2">Create Post</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" id="add" class="mybtn2">Create Post</button>
```

Comment: thanks for writing this out, and this didn't work, but this is part of the problem i presume. I still get 

jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/addItem 500 (Internal)

Comment: and this shows in my url

?body=&_token=qy6hqYJzQSa4zKA8MKP8Ojt1g1Kkz7HZqPefwbph

Comment: please try sending the `'name'` field as `$('textarea#body').val()`

Comment: still doesn't work, and does this help

 
(anonymous) @ app.js:6, does that look right ?

Comment: Remove this namespace from your controller `use App\Http\Requests;`

Comment: All i see is, Additem in red

Comment: Click on the Additem and on the right side you'll be able to see more details under response tab

Comment: i found it its HttpRequest");for(f in d)void 0!==d[f]&&g.setRequestHeader(f,d[f]+"")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141611/discussion-between-linktoahref-and-owl-man).

Comment: I figured the error out it, was a missing token in my master layout. i was missing this            {{ csrf_field() }} in dashboardfile

Comment: however still doesn't post to database